# Is this an IP address?

Tags: validation, ip-address, nsnetservice

I am using **NSNetService** class to resolve IP addresses using MDNS discovery. I get two results:

Something that looks like this:

```
ae60::x:1cdf:x:212
```

(where **x** is another value similar to the others)

And the classic ip address, like: 10.x.x.2

Is the first result also an IP address?

This is the code I am using to retrieve the address:

```
char addressBuffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

for (NSData *data in service.addresses)
{
    memset(addressBuffer, 0, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);

    typedef union {
        struct sockaddr sa;
        struct sockaddr_in ipv4;
        struct sockaddr_in6 ipv6;
    } ip_socket_address;

    ip_socket_address *socketAddress = (ip_socket_address *)[data bytes];

    if (socketAddress && (socketAddress->sa.sa_family == AF_INET || socketAddress->sa.sa_family == AF_INET6))
    {
        const char *addressStr = inet_ntop(
                                           socketAddress->sa.sa_family,
                                           (socketAddress->sa.sa_family == AF_INET ? (void *)&(socketAddress->ipv4.sin_addr) : (void *)&(socketAddress->ipv6.sin6_addr)),
                                           addressBuffer,
                                           sizeof(addressBuffer));

        int port = ntohs(socketAddress->sa.sa_family == AF_INET ? socketAddress->ipv4.sin_port : socketAddress->ipv6.sin6_port);

        if (addressStr && port)
        {
            NSString * address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", addressStr];
            NSLog(@"Found service at %s:%d", addressStr, port);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ae60::x:1cdf:x:212`is an IPv6 adress, while `10.2.x.x.x` is an IPv4 adress. The first one become more popular, because the adress pool of given IPv4 adresses is almost empty.

Answer (score 2):

You've got an [IPv6 IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) like `2001:4860:4860::8888` (the address of one of google's DNS servers).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the string formatted like `ae60::x:1cdf:x:212` is an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **YES**

Long answer: This is an IPv6 Address, the new kind of IP Address. The shorter Version (IPv4, for example 168.192.1.1) is the old one, but a new format was needed which supports a lot more combinations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6